# Detail view not showing data consistently

Tags: python, django

Has anyone run across this problem before? I have a detail view that when I click on it the first time - everything that I would expect to show, does. However, if I refresh the page (ctrl + F5), or navigate away from and back to, only part of it shows up again.

Here's a simplified example of my view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def detail(request, id):
    queryset1 = ...filter(id = id).values().get() 
    queryset2 = ...filter(id = id)
    queryset3 = ...filter(id = id) 
    return render_to_response('template.html',{'q1':queryset1,...}
```

URL:

```
urls = ('',
    url(r'^respondent-detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.detail',name='detail'),
)
```

View:

```
{% include 'includes/header.html' %}
{% include 'includes/navigation.html' %}
{{ q1.x }}
{{ q1.y }}
{{ ...}} 

{% if q2 %}
    {% include 'q2.html' %}
{% else %}
    <p>Post this 2</p>
{% endif %}     

{% if q3 %}
    {% include 'q3.html' %}
{% else %}
    <p>Post this 3</p>
{% endif %}
```

- On first refresh, both q2 and q3 return "Post this"
- On second refresh, q2 returns as expected and q3 returns "Post this"
- On third refresh, q2 and q3 return as expected.

*Update*

I found a solution, adding `@never_cache` at the head of the view removes the issue entirely suggesting that there is something strange happening with the cache when I use a hard refresh. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the development `runserver`?

Comment: No, it's a live server (still closed for development, behind a login wall)

Comment: Do you know what caching headers the web server is sending?

Comment: How would I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Using both [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and [`django-debug-cache-panel`](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-debug-cache-panel) or [`django-cache-panel`](https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-cache-panel) I have been able to sniff out most non-obvious cacheing issues, you can lock the toolbar down so that it's only visible to certain IPs.